# How to get object id of updated document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying to update some data in mongodb and i need the updated object id. i have tried call back function but that returns undefined

```
update(condition, newData, (err, dbData) => console.log(dbData._id));
```

while console dbData returns `{n:1, nModified: 1, ok:1}`
Is there any way to get object id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method to retrieve updated document, try:

```
var updated = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(condition, newData, {new: true});
console.log(updated._id);
```

or using callback style:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(condition, newData, {new: true}, (err,doc) => console.log(doc._id));
```

Comment: This will return the document regardless of whether or not it is updated. Is it possible to only return the result if the update runs?

Comment: @HarryCramer good question, can you open another one since it's a little bit different than what OP wanted to know here

Comment: I've asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506318/get-document-id-in-updateone-post-hook-in-mongoose

Comment: Hi, it seems the op question is about an update where multiple documents can be updated with a filter....I am looking forward for the updateMany returning document ids :)