# Get Document ID in updateOne Post Hook in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How can I find the document `id` that was just updated using the `updateOne`-post hook in Mongoose? It might look something like this:

```
schema.post("updateOne", function (val) {
    if(val.nModified > 0) {
        /// "this" here refers to the schema, not the document...
        /// How can I get the _id field of the document that was modified?
    }
}
```

Currently for the `updateOne`-post hook in Mongoose, `this` refers to the query, not to the document itself being modified. See here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware

It's possible to find the `id` if it was passed in during the query, using `this.getQuery()` but this isn't always applicable——I'm not querying using the `id` field. Thus, the `this.getQuery()` doesn't return to me the data I'm needing.

Does anyone have the solution? I'd rather keep the logging portion in the hooks, where I define my schema, to make my code cleaner, if possible, rather than within my codebase where I'm running the `updateOne` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! You have to re-query for the document, using the `model` that gets passed along with the value, and the query that you passed in. So the post hook looks like this:

```
schema.post("updateOne", function (val) {
    if(val.nModified > 0) {
        const updatedDoc = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
        console.log(updatedDoc._id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Harrison this ain't gonna work if you update the field used for the query,
For instance : await Model. updateOne( { status: 'OK' }, { $set: { status: 'KO' } });